# Potentially wrong and annoying message: “This project uses SQL Server Express LocalDB”

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I’ve upgraded one of my asp.net web applications to Visual Studio 2015. After upgrade I keep getting this message:
“This project uses SQL Server Express LocalDB. Microsoft recomends that you use SQL Server Express with IIS”

[image: This project uses SQL Server Express LocalDB. Microsoft recomends that you use SQL Server Express with IIS]

No matter I choose Yes or No, I always get the pop up upon each F5 run.
I have no LocalDB. This should be a bug in VS05. What are my workaround options?

Comment: This still shows up in VS 15.7, on a project that does not have any EF or LocalDB refs. =<

Answer (score 7):

If your applications are using EF5 then the default is to use LocalDB. you can change that in the web.config to use SQL Server.

Look for:
LocalDb

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">

  <parameters>

    <parameter value="v11.0" />

  </parameters>

</defaultConnectionFactory>
```

and change it to  use Sql Server instead.

Sql Server

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">

  <parameters>

    <parameter value="Data Source=YOURDATABASEHERE; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />

  </parameters>

</defaultConnectionFactory>
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried Mike's solution but still the error would be shown, finally it disappeared after I added full assembly reference with public key tocken.

So basically, I replaced

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

With

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="Data Source=localhost; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Answer (score 1):

This was happening to me because I had a **newly created SQL DB Project**, not connected to anything really, so it was being compiled with the default connection string. Pretty much like [@james-lawruk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88204/james-lawruk) says.

Comment: Instead of removing the project, which I wanted in the solution, I changed the default connection string and that worked.

Comment: coming back to this a bit later, by changing he default connection string, I mean setting the  <TargetConnectionString>in the sqlproj file

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your solution has a reference to a project with a .sqlproj extension. If so, removing the reference should eliminate the issue.